# Facebook Login Button won't show in Android Studio

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, android-studio

I was wondering around the social integration for mobile apps and I made an attempt on Facebook Integration on android studio, everthing went well and I was able to make a Login correctly but everytime I try to put the "com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton" element in the login layout I get the following error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONException
>       at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ProjectClassLoader.load(ProjectClassLoader.java:112)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:52)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ProjectClassLoader.findClass(ProjectClassLoader.java:73)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>       at com.facebook.internal.CallbackManagerImpl$RequestCodeOffset.toRequestCode(CallbackManagerImpl.java:109)
>       at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.(LoginButton.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:379)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:99)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallback.loadView(LayoutlibCallback.java:172)
>       at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
>       at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:132)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:806)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:400)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:332)
>       at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:688)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:677)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:932)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:677)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.render(RenderService.java:815)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:646)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1700(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:82)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:589)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:584)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
>       at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
>       at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Does anyone have an idea for this one?, the help is appreciated.

Comment: You may check out [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=myWu-q8Q2NA&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW4E1wIRZvuXhbFRGWB1grmh) to get some idea.

Comment: This is just an issue with the design tool, it will show up in your app if you run it.

Comment: @MingLi thx for posting the specific, indeed it was a rendering trouble with the design tool :D